# Unsual padding in a website

Tags: html, css

The code below was written by some one else. Instead of using `div` architecture, he has used `tabular` architecture. Now after the **menu** options end, there is a **space** in between the **content** of the page and the **menu**. I have seen the code many a times, checked the **stylesheet** for `padding` or `margin` and observed all the possible reasons that could have caused it but was unable to find the reason for this space. I even tried `margin-top:-100px;` in the content area to see if it moves above but it still did not moved. I would be very thankful if someone can help me out with it. The website is [here](http://www.9amresourceagency.com/about.php).Thanks in advance.
Here is its code,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Lorem Epsum</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="style7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script language="Javascript">
if (document.images) {
     button1 = new Image
     button2 = new Image
     button1.src = 'images/contact.png'
     button2.src = 'images/contactR.png'

     button3 = new Image
     button4 = new Image
     button3.src = 'images/investor.png'
     button4.src = 'images/investorR.png'

     button5 = new Image
     button6 = new Image
     button5.src = 'images/associate.png'
     button6.src = 'images/associateR.png'

     button7 = new Image
     button8 = new Image
     button7.src = 'images/services.png'
     button8.src = 'images/servicesR.png'

     button9 = new Image
     button10 = new Image
     button9.src = 'images/about.png'
     button10.src = 'images/aboutR.png'
 }
</script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">


function SendMemId(ID, Name)
{

    var MyElement = document.getElementById("tester");

    var MyName    = document.getElementById("MyNames");

    document.getElementById('MyNames').innerHTML = (Name);


    MyElement.value = (ID);

    return true;
}//-->
</script>


<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/standard_07_57_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="lite_validation.js"></script>
    <script>
    required.add('name','NOT_EMPTY','Full Name');
    required.add('email','EMAIL','Email Address');
    required.add('message','NOT_EMPTY','Your Message')
    </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
<!--
$(function(){ $("label").inFieldLabels(); });

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>

</head>



<body id="page2" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/aboutR.png','images/servicesR.png','images/associateR.png','images/investorR.png','images/contactR.png')">
<table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="837">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" height="120" background="images/headsmall.png"><table width="100%" height="120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom"><div align="left"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="210" height="110" style="border-style: none"/></a></div></td>
        <td valign="bottom"><table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="about.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','images/aboutR.png',1)"><img src="images/about.png" width="115" height="50" border="0" id="Image6" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="services.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image5','','images/servicesR.png',1)"><img src="images/services.png" width="110" height="50" border="0" id="Image5" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="associates.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image4','','images/associateR.png',1)"><img src="images/associate.png" width="110" height="50" border="0" id="Image4" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="investors.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','images/investorR.png',1)"><img src="images/investor.png" width="110" height="50" border="0" id="Image3" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="contact.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','images/contactR.png',1)"><img src="images/contact.png" width="110" height="50" border="0" id="Image2" /></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <!--<tr>
    <td height="6"></td>
  </tr>-->
  <tr>
    <td  background="images/bg_content.jpg" width="903px" height="477px"><table width="98%" border="0px"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <!-- <tr>
        <td width="409">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="476" height="26">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>-->
      <tr>
        <td width="409" rowspan="5" valign="top"><table width="390" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

          <tr>
            <td height="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="FinalPurpleLook/GlobalPic-AboutUS.png" alt="" width="381" height="237" /></td>
          </tr>

        </table>          </td>
        <td valign="top" class="heading">About us </td>
      </tr>
     <!-- <tr>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>-->
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"class="textSimple">Lorem Epsum is an exclusive private organization engaged in a wide spectrum of global business endeavors from acquisition, development and ownership. Our core market's investments include commercial real estate, energy solutions, information technology, and health wellness.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="textSimple">The philosophy of Lorem Empsum is based on honor, leadership, problem solving, project knowledge, sustainability and innovative ideas. Having powerful, influential connections, is a key element in success. With countless years of experience in  several different industries we are proven to bring success with our connections and expertise knowledge.</td>
      </tr>



      <tr>
        <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>-->
        <td><p align="right" class="footer"> 9am Resource Agency LLC @ 2012               &nbsp;&nbsp; </p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would start over. That source code is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you seriously need to reconsider the Option of **Starting over** and if not then Please also **see the Javascripts and Jqueries** included **which may dynamically make changes** to your CSS or styling properties..

Answer (score 1):

A few quick comments.

First, I have no idea why you have two:

```
  background="images/bg_content.jpg" width="903px" height="477px"
```

in the heading. Someone does not know what they are doing.

Second, I did note that the content adds up to 430 and yet you have your background image set at 477px, e..g, "background="images/bg_content.jpg" width="903px" height="477px" - that might be the cause.

Rick

Comment: I really did not got your first point. Do you mean that I have two copies of that line or what?